# How to migrate from ASP.NET to ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="Feedback.aspx.cs" Inherits="Feedbackajax" Title="Star Bus: Feedback" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
    <style type="text/css">
    </style>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="content1" runat="Server">
    <div id="innertitle">
        <table align="center" style="margin-bottom:25px">
            <tr align="left">
                <td align="left">
                    <strong>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblheat" runat="server" Text="Feedback" Font-Size="X-Large" ForeColor="#F7990D"></asp:Label>
                    </strong>
                    <br />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="Server">
    <div id="rightContent">
        <div class="mainText" id="maintextBox">
            <!-- Body Content Starts -->
            <div id="formBody" style="margin:0 auto;text-align:center">
                <table cellspacing="3" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" style="text-align:left">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td height="30">
                                <strong><span>Name: </span></strong>
                            </td>
                            <td valign="middle">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtname" runat="server" />
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvnaem" ErrorMessage="*" ControlToValidate="txtname"
                                                            runat="server" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td height="30">
                                <strong><span>Email:</span></strong>
                            </td>
                            <td valign="middle">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtemail" runat="server" />
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvemail" ErrorMessage="*" ControlToValidate="txtemail"
                                                            runat="server" />
                                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Enter the Vaild Email ID"
                                                                ControlToValidate="txtemail" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td height="30">
                                <strong><span>Phone:</span></strong>
                            </td>
                            <td valign="middle">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtph" runat="server" />
                                <asp:RangeValidator ID="rangeph" ControlToValidate="txtph" Text="Invalid Phone" Type="Double"
                                                    MinimumValue="1" MaximumValue="9999999999" runat="server" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td height="30">
                                <strong><span>Subject:</span></strong>
                            </td>
                            <td valign="middle">
                                <div id="txtHint">
                                    <asp:DropDownList CssClass="form" tyle="width: 130px" ID="dlsubject" runat="server"
                                                      Width="133px">
                                        <asp:ListItem Text="Bus service" Value="Bus service"></asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem Text="website" Value="website"></asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem Text="schedules" Value="schedules"></asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem Text="Other" Value="Other"></asp:ListItem>
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <strong><span style="vertical-align:middle">Comment:</span></strong><br />(Max 1000 char)
                            </td>
                            <td class="style1">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtcomment" runat="server" MaxLength="1000" TextMode="MultiLine"
                                             Height="75px" Width="235px" />
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvcomment" ErrorMessage="*" ControlToValidate="txtcomment"
                                                            runat="server" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td colspan="2">
                                <asp:Button ID="btnsubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnsubmit_Click" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <!-- Body Content Ends -->
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder3" runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content5" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder4" runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content6" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
```

This is my ASP.NET project that I have already created. But now I have the need to convert this project to ASP.NET Core 2.1 or later.

I am finding it difficult to do it as there is a lot that has changed.

I would like to get the assistance of the expertise on how I could do it please.

My greatest problem is not knowing how to replace certain place holders and tag helpers to the newer version.

Regards

Comment: History: 20++ years ago, there were server-side scripting languages like PHP, JSP ... and "classic ASP".  ASP.Net was closely tied to "classic ASP".  In contrast, ASP.Net MVC is a "framework".  It's very different - and requires a different mindset - than ASP.Net.  ASP.Net Core (and now, ASP.Net 5) is also MVC-based.  BOTTOM LINE: forget your legacy "ASP" code; learn ASP.Net Core/ASP.Net 5 as a "web framework".

Comment: [Blazor for ASP.NET Web Forms Developers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/blazor-for-web-forms-developers/)

Comment: `My greatest problem is not knowing how to replace certain place holders and tag helpers to the newer version.` In ASP.NET Core app, you can put shared content or common layout in [`_Layout.cshtml`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/layout?view=aspnetcore-5.0), and use [Tag Helpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro?view=aspnetcore-5.0) to create and render HTML elements in Razor views or [partial view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-5.0).